# How to install an app from Android market to Android simulator?

Tags: android

1. How do I install an app from Android market to the emulator?
2. How do I install an app in the simulator by scanning a [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code)?
3. How do I install a .APK file in the simulator?

Is there any method or tutorial?

Comment: @Cristian LMGTFY links are considered offensive and a bad attitude in SO. See this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android Market](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Market) is not available on emulators for security reasons. You may install [APKs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29). Refer to *[Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)*.

Comment: Ya With can DDMS also ... but if i haven't android mobile and i wan to test app are in market than .. what to do ?

Comment: if u are developing an app you can create an apk and test u can't have any from the market

Comment: i know with simulator my created app i can test .... but suppose your app .apk file only available on market than ? how can i test ?

Comment: not possible may be you can download it on some android device and then by through hacking may get that apk  otherwise it doesn't seems possible to me to get an apk file from android market

Answer (score 0):

To install an application from Google Play Store (formerly known as Android Market) onto an Android emulator:

1. Purchase, borrow or steal an Android device which has access to the Play Store.
2. Enable USB Debugging on the Android device and connect it to your development computer.
3. Go to the Google Play Store and download your application.
4. Pull the app from the device to your computer:

   ```
   adb -d pull /data/app/com.example.myapp-1.apk MyApp.apk
   ```
5. Install the app to your emulator:

   ```
   adb -e install MyApp.apk
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You can download the APK file. Use the Android SDK tools to install it. In a commandline window do:

```
yoursdk\tools\adb install youapp
```